# Defining multiple outputs in Logstash whilst handling potential unavailability of an Elasticsearch instance

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I have two outputs configured for Logstash as I need the data to be delivered to two separate Elasticsearch nodes in different locations.

A snippet of the configuration is below (redacted where required):

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "https://host1.local:9200" ]
    cacert => '/etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt'
    user => XXXXX
    password => XXXXX
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
 }

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "https://host2.local:9200" ]
    cacert => '/etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt'
    user => XXXXX
    password => XXXXX
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

During testing I've noticed that if one of the ES instances, `host1.local` or `host2.local` is unavailable, Logstash fails to process/deliver data to the other, even though it's available.

Is there a modification I can make to the configuration that will allow data to be delivered to the available Elasticsearch instance, even if the other dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logstash has an at-least-once delivery model. If [persistent queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html) are not enabled data can be lost across a restart, but otherwise, logstash will delivery events to *all* of the outputs at least once. As a result, if one output becomes unreachable the queue (either in-memory or persistent) will back up and block processing. You can use persistent queues and pipeline-to-pipeline communication with an [output isolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#output-isolator-pattern) pattern to avoid stalling one output when another is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @Badger's answer, you will need to use the [output isolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#output-isolator-pattern) pattern they suggested. As you observed, when one `output` is blocked, it prevents the other outputs from functioning. This is also noted in the docs

> Logstash, by default, is blocked when any single output is down.

This solution can be used for any `output` and is not unique to Elasticsearch. Here is a code sample of how it would work for your example.

```
# config/pipelines.yml
- pipeline.id: intake
  config.string: |
    input { ... }
    output { pipeline { send_to => [es-host1, es-host2] } }
- pipeline.id: buffered-es-host1
  queue.type: persisted
  config.string: |
    input { pipeline { address => es-host1 } }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "https://host1.local:9200" ]
      cacert => '/etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt'
      user => XXXXX
      password => XXXXX
      index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
- pipeline.id: buffered-es-host2
  queue.type: persisted
  config.string: |
    input { pipeline { address => es-host2 } }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "https://host2.local:9200" ]
        cacert => '/etc/logstash/config/certs/ca.crt'
        user => XXXXX
        password => XXXXX
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
```

You can follow [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) for running multiple pipelines, but you need to pass into the [command line](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-command-line.html) the parameter `path.settings` with the new `config/pipelines.yml` file.

```
bin/logstash --path.settings config/pipelines.yml
```